# "Multiple controls with the same ID 'id' were found" Error when I try to use rating cotrol in ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net

I am stuck on this error:

> **"Multiple controls with the same ID 'id' were found"**

I got this error when i tried to add rating control in ASP.NET web page. Here is the code for rating control:

```
<myrating:Rating ID="LikeRating1" runat="server" 
                CurrentRating="3" 
                MaxRating="5" 
                StarCssClass="ratingStar" 
                WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar" 
                FilledStarCssClass="filledRatingStar" 
                EmptyStarCssClass="emptyRatingStar" 
                OnChanged="LikeRating_Changed"
                style="float: left;">
</myrating:Rating>
```

At start of the page i have added this line also:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="myrating" %>
```

Why I am getting this error than?? I don't think that there are any IDs conflict in this file because i get this error when i added this rating control.
Please help, thanks.

Comment: Can you search from your page the ID "LikeRating1"

Comment: yes i searched it, its a unique ID in this page. Why i am getting this stupid error!!! This is insane...

Comment: Do you get the error when you run the application?  If so, what line of code throws the error?

Comment: Can we see your code-behind for this page?

Comment: how can i share code here? its long and there is characters limit here...

Comment: try to isolate the error in a new blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the rating control that does this?
In the source (website source, in the browser), have you searched for id="id" alone?
Are you adding controls dynamically, without setting their ID?

Answer (score 0):

There is another possibility in case if it gives the same error after removing 1st detected control, You must be overriding the base.SomeMethod... and it  's being called when its already overrided .
eg FrameworkInitilize (){ // base.FrameworkInitilize() }
and again in some_event[page_Load]{FrameworkInitilize ()}